# Including C Code in C++

Tags: c++, c, g++

I'm trying to include C code into a simple C++ program but I ran into an unexpected problem - when I try to compile the program g++ gives the following error:

```
/tmp/cccYLHsB.o: In function `main':
test1.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `add'
```

I searched for a solution and found this tutorial:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/overview-mixing-langs.html

There seems to be no difference to my program so I'm a bit lost...

My C++ program looks like this:

test1.ccp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" {
#include "sample1.h"
}

int main(void)
{
    int x= add(3);

    cout << "the current value of x is " << x << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The sample1 header and function look like this:

sample1.h

```
#include <stdio.h>

double add(const double a);
```

sample1.c

```
#include "sample1.h"

double add(const double a)
{
    printf("Hello World\n");

        return a + a;
}
```

For compilation I first compile a test1.o with g++ and sample1.o with gcc (tried g++ also but makes no difference)

```
g++ -c test1.cpp

gcc -c sample1.c
```

That works as expected. Afterwards I try to link the program like this:

```
g++ sample1.o test1.o -o test
```

This is where I get the error mentioned above

```
test1.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `add'
```

I have the feeling that I'm missing something important but just can't see it.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Regards

jules

Comment: g++ does name mangling , due to that you I think add is not resolved

Comment: Do you ever compile `sample1.h`?

Comment: This should work, as far as I can see. What does the command `nm sample1.o` output?

Comment: Works here as posted (gcc 4.6.2). What version are you using?

Comment: With the exact source code and command line for compiling and linking, I cannot reproduce this - it works as expected. Are you doing exactly what you've posted here ?

Comment: @JacobAbrahams how often do you compile a header file? Most people tend to only #include them, as the OP shows he has done.

Comment: @pmg he has it surrounding the #include already; one level is enough, no?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works just as expected. Make sure you haven't accidentally compiled `sample1.c` with `g++`.

Comment: And there's an easy way to find out, run `nm sample1.o`, there should be 1 non-mangled symbol for `add` , if there isn't, then something else than `gcc -c sample1.c` generated the sample1.o file.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the problem! I compiled both files with g++

Answer (score 3):

It works on my machine. Try GCC 4.7.0