# How to properly link ed25519-donna with c++? (where is the -mbits flag?)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, ed25519-donna

I've found this [great question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477807/including-c-code-in-c) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329159/including-c-headers-inside-a-c-program) which seems even greater where productivity's concerned.

However, the [ed25519-donna docs](https://github.com/floodyberry/ed25519-donna) suggest

> To use the code, link against ed25519.o -mbits and:
>
> `#include "ed25519.h"`

First, I can't find the `-mbits` flag.  More importantly is it possible to use the technique in the more productive answer?

---

I was afraid to considering the importance, but I tried to use the techniques above combined  with recommendations from the docs without the `-mbits` flag

```
g++  -o server ed25519-donna-master/ed25519.o myserver -std=c++0x -I ~/myserver -D_WEBSOCKETPP_CPP11_STL_ -D_WEBSOCKETPP_NO_CPP11_REGEX_ -lboost_regex -lboost_system -L/usr/lib -lssl -lcrypto -pthread -lconfig++ -lpqxx -lboost_thread
```

and this is the result

```
myserver: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 21
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:/build/buildd/eglibc-2.17/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:119: first defined here
myserver: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 7
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 8
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 9
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o(.debug_ranges): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 4
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o(.debug_ranges): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 4
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o(.debug_ranges): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 5
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o(.debug_ranges): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 5
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
myserver: In function `__data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
myserver: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 4
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o(.debug_line): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 5
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:/build/buildd/eglibc-2.17/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/crti.S:64: first defined here
myserver: In function `__data_start':
(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
myserver:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtend.o:(.tm_clone_table+0x0): multiple definition of `__TMC_END__'
myserver:(.data+0x38): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in myserver(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think I need the `-mbits` flag, but I can't find it.  [There are a few](http://linux.die.net/man/1/g++) `mbit` type flags for `gcc`.  Can one of those be used?  If so, which one?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I apologize Jonathon Reinhart for neglecting those tags, and thank you for looking!  I have added `gcc` and `g++`.

Comment: In your C++ code, did you do this: `extern "C" { #include "ed25519.h" }`?

Comment: @MarkkuK. Thank you Markku K.!  Yes, I tried both with and without; interestingly, the errors are the same.  Do you know what should be done about the `-mbits` flag?  Thank you so very much in advance!

Comment: That seems to mean use `-m64` on a 64-bit system and use `-m32` on a 32-bit system. Looks like `-m64` for you.

Comment: @MarkkuK. Thank you for the information on mbits!  The errors go away if I leave the `include` and remove the `ed25519.o`.  As soon as I can test, I will post an answer.

Comment: Actually, I just looked at your compile command. Are you trying to create a new executable called 'server', by linking ed25519.o with an existing executable called 'myserver'? That is probably the source of most of your problems -- you need to link ed25519.o with the .o files used to create 'myserver' instead.

Comment: @MarkkuK. That did it!  Thank you very much Markku K.!  Would you mind upgrading to an answer?  Thank you so very much in advance Markku K.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to create a new executable called 'server', by linking ed25519.o with an existing executable called 'myserver'? That is probably the source of most of your problems -- you need to link ed25519.o with the .o files used to create 'myserver' instead.

As far as the `-mbits` option, I think they mean use `-m32` or `-m64`, depending on the architecture of the machine you are compiling on. So, for you that means use `-m64`.